# CSRF Token in Typescript, showing '{' or ';' expected and Parameter declaration expected

Tags: jquery, typescript, django-csrf

I have a CSRF Token script inside my typescript file,

```
getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;

    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i ++) {
          var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length +1));
            break ;
          }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }

  csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if(!this.csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

when I try to run it, it gives me this 2 error

[image]

[image]

Anyone know why ?? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You cannot have piece of code in a class definition. It should be inside some method of the class.

Comment: After I do the editting, I run the ionic serve, and I have this error Unexpected value 'ProblemPage' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed all of your jQuery document ready code in a strange location.

This is minimally changed version that compiles.

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      var csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');
      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
          if (!this.csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;

      if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i ++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length +1));
              break ;
            }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
  }

  csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }

}
```

Comment: After I do the editting, I run the ionic serve, and I have this error

Unexpected value 'ProblemPage' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation